# Fails to process OCR with Text OCR API samples

Tags: java, android, ocr

I tried two android-java text OCR samples, and each time it crashes violently (no exception catch) on instruction

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();
```

In the last sample (Komamitsu one), here is the log content:

```
11-27 17:58:59.101 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
11-27 17:58:59.197 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via fast routecom.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: V2 version check failed
11-27 17:58:59.213 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
11-27 17:58:59.621 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
11-27 17:58:59.754 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000030/n/arm64-v8a
11-27 17:59:00.039 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample E/native: jni_helper.cc:170 GetContents failed: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/ocr/data/models/semanticlift_engine_0.2.bincfg
11-27 17:59:00.039 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample A/native: timer.cc:38 Check failed: x >= 1 (0 vs. 1) 
11-27 17:59:00.039 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample A/native: terminating.
11-27 17:59:00.039 5997-5997/org.komamitsu.android_ocrsample A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5997 (droid_ocrsample)

                                                                     [ 11-27 17:59:00.039   403:  403 W/         ]
                                                                     debuggerd: handling request: pid=5997 uid=10189 gid=10189 tid=5997
```

Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: First you need to have google play in your device. I Had this issue because of have low free storage in internal storage. This is official google examples for vision api usage. Try this one. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples

Comment: Thanks. But I have already google play device. And I had already the same crash with android-vision sample.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I can't install "Mobile Vision" API, so  "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision". I can't do that programatically, and I don't find in the play store the corresponding application.